# Azure Purview "Register Sources" Tile missing in Studio

Tags: azure, azure-purview

I have a personal Azure subscription where I am the owner. I provisioned an Azure Purview account on my subscription.

When opening Purview Studio, I do not see the option to "Register Sources". The only options I have are "Browse Assets", "Manage Glossary" and "Knowledge Center".

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: What region is your Purview account created in? I would recommend  give a try clearing browser cache and reopen purview studio again to see if there is any change.

Comment: My Purview account is in Central India. I have tried in Incognito and on different machines. Still the same issue.

Comment: Hmm.. this looks strange. For deeper investigation and immediate assistance we request you to please file a support ticket. If you don't have a support plan, please reach out in Microsoft Q&A (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/products/), one of our engineers will assist you.

Answer (score 0):

> (UPDATE: Sep 3, 2021): Azure Purview accounts created on or after August 18, 2021 will not show `Register Source` tile in the Home page.

[image]

> You can go to Data Map tab where you will find sources and here you can register a new source.

For more detail refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/how-to-create-and-manage-collections

[image]

---

This is an expected behaviour based on the permissions you have on the Azure Purview account.

> The quick access buttons give access to frequently used functions of the application. The buttons that are presented, **depend on the role assigned to your user account**.

[image]

For more details, refer to Use [Purview Studio - Home Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/purview/use-purview-studio#home-page).

Comment: This is my personal Azure account. So I am the owner of the account. Additionally I have given myself access to Data Curator, Data Reader and Data Source administrator. But I dont see the option still. Interestingly I found the "Sources" option under "Data Map" from the left side menu. Using that I am able to register and scan resources.

Comment: Hi @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT, thanks for the response. Yes I did see the "Sources" option under Data Map allows to register sources. However I am still slightly unclear regarding the 4 bullet points; esp the 3rd one where it says if I have data source admin + data curator then I should see Register Data Sources tile. But that doesnt seem to be the case. My user has these roles under Collections in Purview Studio but I do not see the tile. Is it correct to say that Register Data Sources as a Tile will never be available on the home page?

Comment: @ankitp Thanks for bringing this to our attention. I would request you to leave a feedback at the bottom of the document. We will review the feedback and update you accordingly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Goto DataMap > Data Sources > Register Source

There you may add different kind of sources.

[image]